# How to fix Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\venv\\scripts\\nt\\python_d.exe'

Tags: python-3.x, python-venv

I'm using the latest version of Python on Windows and I'm trying to use `venv` with the following code:

```
C:\envs> py -m venv test
```

Even if it actually creates the `venv`, it returns this error and I don't understand why. 
Moreover I can't activate the `venv`, the code

```
C:\envs> C:\envs\test\Scripts\activate.bat
```

returns

> "C:\envs\test\Scripts\activate.bat" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Solved. It is a bug when debug binaries are installed. See https://bugs.python.org/issue36441

Answer (score 23):

I am using python version 3.7.3 it gave me error states that **"No such file or directory: 'C:\python37\lib\venv\scripts\nt\python_d.exe'"** at the time of creation of project in pycharm.

I copied following files from python location(**C:\Program Files\Python37**) to the (**C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\venv\scripts\nt**) and it worked for me

**1) python_d.exe

2) python_d.pdb

3) pythonw_d.exe

4) pythonw_d.pdb**

Answer (score 8):

As Villani mentioned in his own comment, it's a debug binaries problem.

It will be fixed in the upcoming 3.7.4 release. (Planned for 24/06)

Either downgrade to 3.7.2 or install without debug binaries.

Comment: I just gave a try to `Python 3.7.4rc1` and this issue is gone

Answer (score 4):

In Anaconda prompt type these commands:

```
conda remove anaconda
conda update python
conda list --show-channel-urls | findstr python
python -m venv venv
```

Answer (score 2):

for me what fixed the issue was copying the **python_d.exe** and **python_d.pdb** from **C:\Program Files\Python37** to **C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\venv\scripts\nt**

hope this solves your problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is , your virtual environment could not find debugger resources. The venv module's resources dont have those resources (probably a bug). The easy solution is.

1. Fix the venv module resources first: Copy debugger symbols to venv resources. In your python installation directory **copy python_d.pdb, python_d.exe, pythonw_d.pdb, pythonw_d.exe** and past inside **(installation directory) Lib>venv>scripts>nt**. In this nt folder should also have (already present) **python.exe , python.pdb , pythonw.exe, pythonw.pdb**
2. Now, try to create virtual environment using

   python -m venv py37dev

Answer (score 1):

These steps worked for me

```
conda update --force conda
conda update python
conda list --show-channel-urls | findstr python
python -m venv venv
```

Answer (score 0):

I update python and bug fixed

```
conda update --force conda
```

Answer (score 0):

```
conda remove anaconda
conda update python
python -m venv venv
```

This will resolve it but your main Python interpreter will run from the conda environment & it will prompt the error below but it will work just fine.

"This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated."